# Iterar em vários arquivos de texto

Tags: python, arquivo, iterator

Boa tarde. Tenho o seguinte objetivo: Tenho uma série de arquivos de texto e desejo criar um script para iterar sobre todos eles e contar quantas vezes determinadas strings aparecem neles.

Eu consegui realizar o script para o caso de um único arquivo. Mas estou com dificuldades para realizar o procedimento de contagem no caso de usar uma iteração em múltiplos arquivos.

Segue abaixo a minha tentativa de código:

```
# Eu organizei as strings que devem ser localizadas por meio de um dicionário. O dicionário abaixo é apenas exemplificativo, na realidade o do meu código é bem mais extenso.
mi = {"key1": value1, "key2": value2}

# Os arquivos que desejo realizar a varredura estão nomeados segundo um determinado padrão, por exemplo, "ABC 01.2015.txt ; ABC 02.2015.txt e etc.

# O teste consiste em 3 arquivos, no qual em cada um deles cada valor do meu dicionário deve aparecer uma única vez. Dessa maneira, o código deve resultar em 3 contagens para cada valor do meu dicionário. 

# Em seguida criarei um dicionário ordenado por key, bem como uma lista vazia que desejo adicionar a contagem correspondente a cada string.

import collections
od_mi = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(mi.items()))
count_occur = list()
soma = 0
for i in range(2,5):
    for value in od_mi.values():
        x = "ABC" + " " + str(i) +".2015.txt"
        data = open(x, "r").read()
        contar = data.count(value)
        soma += contar
        count_occur.append(soma)
print count_occur
#O output para a minha lista está incorreto, vejam abaixo:
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 256, 257, 258, 259, 260, 261, 262, 263, 264, 265, 266, 267, 268, 269, 270, 271, 272, 273, 274, 275, 276, 277, 278, 279, 280, 281, 282, 283, 284, 285, 286, 287, 288, 289, 290, 291, 292, 293, 294, 295, 296, 297, 298, 299, 300, 301, 302, 303, 304, 305, 306, 307, 308, 309, 310, 311, 312, 313, 314, 315, 316, 317, 318, 319, 320, 321, 322, 323, 324, 325, 326, 327, 328, 329, 330, 331, 332, 333, 334, 335, 336, 337, 338, 339, 340, 341, 342, 343, 344, 345, 346, 347, 348, 349, 350, 351, 352, 353, 354, 355, 356, 357, 358, 359, 360, 361, 362, 363, 364, 365, 366, 367, 368, 369, 370, 371, 372, 373, 374, 375, 376, 377, 378, 379, 380, 381, 382, 383, 384]

#Em seguida tentei modificar o meu código e apenas consegui com que o output fosse o registro da contagem apenas do último arquivo lido, na realidade ele sobrescreveu os dados a cada novo arquivo.
count_occur = list()
for i in range(2,5):
for value in od_mi.values():
    x = "ABC" + " " + str(i) +".2015.txt"
    data = open(x, "r").read()
    contar = data.count(value)
    count_occur.append(contar)
print count_occur
output: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar ? Sou novo em programação de modo geral, quaisquer informações adicionais necessárias que necessitem podem falar!

Answer (score 1):

Se quiser contar quantas vezes as palavras aparece, por arquivo:

```
import os

strings = ['uma', 'frase']

files = [f for f in os.listdir("/tmp") if f.startswith('arq') and f.endswith('.txt')]

for filename in files:
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        data = f.read()
        for s in strings:
            print filename, s, data.count(s)
```

Se quiser contar quantas vezes as palavras somando todos os arquivos:

```
counts = {}
for filename in files:
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        data = f.read()
        for s in strings:
            if s in counts.keys():
                counts[s] += data.count(s)
            else:
                counts[s] = data.count(s)
print counts
```

Para esse exemplo eu crie os seguintes arquivos:

```
/tmp/arq1.txt:
uma frase qualquer

/tmp/arq2.txt:
uma outra frase qualquer

/tmp/arq3.txt:
aqui tem uma frase diferente

/tmp/arq4.txt:
uma frase com a palavra frase
```

Comment: Uma alternativa bem interessante para listar os arquivos é a função [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html). Algo como `files = glob("/tmp/arq*.txt")`.